# is there any way to separate folders from subfolders and files in folder bar

Tags: browser, visual-studio-code, directory, subdirectory

example:
It is all very close and it is confusing when it comes to knowing in which folder the files are, many times I must use the windows explorer to be sure.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVaeZ.png

Comment: It is not clear to me from your question what you are talking about. From the screenshot snippet that you link to, your questions seems to be about the visual layout in some sort of code editor or IDE, but you don't explain which one.
You will get more useful responses if you give some more context and also tag your question with relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm talking about visual studio code, I think my post was made on this software.
I'm new to this site, and I don't quite understand how this is going, but from the visual studio code website, from microsoft they sent me here.

Comment: Thank you very much, and a thousand apologies for my mistake?